# How to treat null value on an integer column

Tags: sql, postgresql, null

I have an integer column that can contain nothing.
I can't set the default value to 0 cause it is an external reference to another table and the 0 value is not allowed.

So, I can have rows like

```
id | description  | value    
1  | a null value |     
2  | ok value     | 3
```

The query

```
 select id from table where value=null
```

does not work: it should give me the first row, but it doesn't!
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You need to understand `NULL` when working with relational databases. Start by reading the excellent manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparison.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL when working with `NULL` values you have to use `IS NULL` or if you want the inverse: `IS NOT NULL`.